# Spring controller redirect to another module

Tags: java, web-services, spring-mvc

I need some help.

I have an app, in which backend and frontent are separated(backend - java + spring, frontent - angularjs), so they are located in different modules in project and are connected via rest protocol.

On the request with mapping "/" I should redirect user to page index.html, but this html file is located not in the same package and module of application as my spring controller.

I know, that I can user internalresourceviewresolver to redirect user to view, which is located in web-inf folder. But it is not my case..

Can you help me with this problem please? How can I redirect user to view in another module?

Structure of application:

[image]

Comment: How the modules are linked ? 
Where is index.html respect to source folder?

Comment: You use Maven or a standard project layout ? The 2 modules are in the same project ?

Comment: @Massimo I use maven. Yes, modules are in the same repository and project.

Comment: If you want to call the service from backend you can call it Restfully just using its URL..See this link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432167/make-a-rest-url-call-to-another-service-by-filling-the-details-from-the-form

Answer (score 0):

You can put index.html in src/main/webapp (not in WEB-INF) folder and let serving the index.html file as is. No configuration needed.

Additionally your rest controllers should respond not on / but, by example on /rest/something, you can annotate directely the controllers classes

Comment: I can't move my index.html file

Comment: Where is located in your final war/ear?

Comment: I'am using tomcat-embed, so my jar is located in `client-intake-backend-web/target`

Comment: I mean were is index.html inside your war/ear/jar and where is WEB-INF

Comment: Said in other way, even if i don't know about tomcat embed or your layout but it looks like your html can respond directly..maybe is only my idea but have a look at it